# Compressing High Resolution Satellite Images

Tags: compression, image, jpeg2000, satellite

Please advise the best way to compress satellite Image. Details

Uncompressed size - 60 gb
Uncompressed format - IMG
4 Bands (To be retained after compression)
Preferred compression format - JPEG2000
Lossy enough to aid in Visual analysis.

Thanks
Monika

Comment: You've already said that you're using JPEG2000, which will work.  What do you have a question about?

Comment: Are you asking how much compression to apply to the image so it is acceptable for some other work? For example 80% of compression...?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm interpreting your question correctly, you'll already need to look at the file format defined in  JPEG2000 Part 2 ("JPX") because of the multiple bands.  Beyond that, because you are asking for "visually lossless" (e.g. lossy compression but tuned to the point where you can't see it), you'll need to experiment with various settings using your own files until you achieve what you want.  For a small discussion on how the Internet Archive did this with print materials, see [A Status Report on JPEG 2000 Implementation for Still Images: The UConn Survey](http://digitalcommons.uconn.edu/libr_pubs/19/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Well, probably I should have given more details. I wanted to know which would be the best software to do this compression. WE tried ArcGIS and it is taking unusally long time - for 25 gb it took almost 2 days+; same with ERDAS. The hardware configuration is reasonable. Do you think just upgrading to speed up will help or is there any other better way of going about it?

Comment: Hmmm -- that seems unusually long.  I'm most familiar with the Kakadu Software implementation, and it comes with a "speed pack" to support higher speed requirements.  You might try looking at that; good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the Kakadu JPEG 2000 software.  It's really fast.

The summary of one of their time tests, which sounds in line with our observed results:

> '"There is an example on the spreadsheet involving a 13.3K x 13.3K RGB image (531 MBytes), being compressed to 2 bits/pixel, at 0.145 pictures/second, using the speedpack on a standard 2.4 GB core-2 duo machine.  From this, it can be inferred that compressing 60 MB down to 5 MB (12:1 is 2 bits/pixel for RGB, although colour properties were not specified in the original request) should occur at a rate of 1.2 pictures/second.  Compressing to the slightly lower target size of 4 MB will be a little bit faster."
>
> http://www.kakadusoftware.com/